# Notifications not showing on specific time and date

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications, android-pendingintent

I am working on an app that will remind the user of a particular event at a specific time and date. I have set the notifications correctly but they sometimes work and sometimes not.

I am using put extra and get extra to send clicked position to my receiver class(sending position from BuddhaEvent class to Myreceiver class). So if user clicks on position 1 then notification 1 should be triggered from the message class. I am put log statements in each position call please check it.

The output of the log statement is like this:

`POSITION0 : 0
 POSITION0 : 0
 POSITION1: 1
 POSITION0 : 0
 POSITION2 : 2`

And this is the log statement when 4 notifications are shown

```
POSITION0 : 0
```

`POSITION0 : 0
POSITION1: 1
POSITION0 : 0
POSITION2 : 2
POSITION0 : 0
POSITION3 : 3`

There is a pattern here, 0 is always being called before a notification!!!

I don’t know what’s going on. The first notification works fine but after that the notifications are just random. Most of the times notifications 2 and 3 come at the same time and sometimes 2 waits for the 3 to come. 
Another problem I noticed is that when I slide down for notifications, all of the notifications have the same time of delivery. I have set different id for each notification.

What I am thinking is that, the put extra and get extra are done incorrectly. I would really appreciate if someone can help me figure out the problem.

UPDATE: SO WHEN I CLICK FIRST ITEM IN THE LIST, NOTIFICATION 1 SHOWS UP. IF I CLICK ON ITEM 2, THEN NOTIFICATION 1 AND 2 SHOW UP AT THE SAME TIME. WHEN I CLICK ON ITEM 3 NOTIFICATION 3 AND 1 SHOW UP.
Thanks in advance

UPDATE2: THE PROGRAM WAS CALLING 0 EVERY TIME, I DECIDED TO CHANGE THE PUT POSITION0 TO SOMETHING DIFFERENT AND NOW ONLY ONE NOTIFICATION SHOWS AT TIME(THIS ONLY WORKS WHEN TIME HAS PASSED) **BUT WHEN I TRY TO SCHEDULE NOTIFICATIONS EVENTS SAME PROBLEM EXITS(LIKE SHOWING TWO NOTIFICATIONS AT THE SAME TIME).**

This is my Main class `public class BuddhaEvent extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public List myList = new ArrayList();
    android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder notification;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_buddhism_event);


    fill_eventsList();
    fill_ListView();
    clickResponse();

    Button buddah_button_event = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_event_back_buddhism);
    buddah_button_event.setOnClickListener(this);


}

private void fill_eventsList() {
    myList.add(new list("Jan-24", R.drawable.chris, "Mahayana countries the new year starts on the first full moon day in January.", "Mahayana New Year"));
    myList.add(new list("Feb-2", R.drawable.chris, "Chinese festival celebrated at the turn of the traditional lunisolar Chinese calendar.", "Chinese New Year"));
    myList.add(new list("Feb-15", R.drawable.chris, "Celebrates the day when the Buddha is said to have achieved Parinirvana, or complete Nirvana", "Nirvana Day"));
    myList.add(new list("Mar-23", R.drawable.chris, "Celebration in honour of the Sangha, or the Buddhist community", "Magha Puja Day"));
    myList.add(new list("Apr-22", R.drawable.chris, "Buddhist New Year", "Theravada New Year"));
    myList.add(new list("May-15", R.drawable.chris, "Celebrates the Buddha's birthday", "Wesak - Buddha Day"));
    myList.add(new list("Jul-11", R.drawable.chris, "Honor the spirits of one's ancestors.", "Obon"));
    myList.add(new list("Jul-19", R.drawable.chris, "Celebrates Buddha's teachings of peace and enlightenment", "Asala - Dharma Day"));
    myList.add(new list("Dec-8", R.drawable.chris, "The day that the historical Buddha, Siddhartha Gautama (Shakyamuni), experienced enlightenment", "Bodhi Day"));

}

private void fill_ListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<list> listArrayAdapter = new myListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_eventsView);
    list.setAdapter(listArrayAdapter);

}

public void clickResponse() {
    ListView l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_eventsView);
    if (l != null) {
        l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View viewClicked,
                                    final int position, long id) {


                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        BuddhaEvent.this);
                alert.setTitle("Reminder!!");
                alert.setMessage("Do you want to be reminded of this event in future?");
                alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d("OUTSIDE", "CHECKING WHICH IS CLICKED    : " + which);

                        if (position == 0) {
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
                            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);
                            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
                            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);
                            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class);
                            intent.putExtra("position0", position);


                            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

                        }

                        if (position == 1) {
                            Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();

                            calendar2.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
                            calendar2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);

                            calendar2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
                            calendar2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 3);
                            calendar2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


                            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class);
                            intent2.putExtra("position1",position );



                            PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 101, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                            AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                            alarmManager2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent2);
                        }

                        if (position == 2) {

                            Calendar calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();

                            calendar3.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
                            calendar3.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);

                            calendar3.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
                            calendar3.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 4);
                            calendar3.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


                            Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class);
                            intent3.putExtra("position2", position);


                            PendingIntent  pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 105, intent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar3.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent3);
                        }


                        if (position == 3) {

                            Calendar calendar4 = Calendar.getInstance();

                            calendar4.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
                            calendar4.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);

                            calendar4.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
                            calendar4.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
                            calendar4.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


                            Intent intent4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class);
                            intent4.putExtra("position3", position);


                            PendingIntent  pendingIntent4 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 102, intent4, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                            AlarmManager alarmManager4 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                            alarmManager4.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar4.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent4);
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                alert.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alert.show();
            }
        });
    }
}


private class myListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<list> {
    public myListAdapter() {
        super(BuddhaEvent.this, R.layout.custom_events_layout, myList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_events_layout, parent, false);
        }
        list current_list = myList.get(position);


        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_image);
        imageView.setImageResource(current_list.getIconId());


        TextView titleTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_event);
        titleTxt.setText(current_list.getName());

        EditText text = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_desp);
        text.setText(current_list.getDetails());


        TextView date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_date);
        date.setText(current_list.getDate());

        return itemView;
    }


}


public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(BuddhaEvent.this, BuddhaScreen.class));
}
```

}
`
This is MyReceiver class that extends Broadcast receiver

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


    if(bundle==null){
        return;
    }else{
        if(bundle.getInt("position0")==0){
            Log.d("INSIDE", "POSITION0 : " + bundle.getInt("position0"));

            Utils utils = new Utils();
            utils.generateNotification(context);
        }

        if(bundle.getInt("position1")==1){
            Log.d("INSIDE", "POSITION1: " + bundle.getInt("position1"));

            Utils utils = new Utils();
            utils.generateNotification2(context);
        }

        if(bundle.getInt("position2")==2){
            Log.d("INSIDE", "POSITION2 : " + bundle.getInt("position2"));

            Utils utils = new Utils();
            utils.generateNotification3(context);
        }

        if(bundle.getInt("position3")==3){
            Log.d("INSIDE", "POSITION3 : " + bundle.getInt("position3"));

            Utils utils = new Utils();
            utils.generateNotification4(context);
        }
    }


}
```

}

This is my utils class that keeps track of the notifications

```
public class Utils {


public void generateNotification(Context context) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context, BuddhaNow.class);
    // replace the old activity if there is a case that it is already opened
    repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, repeating_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle("Notification Title1")
            .setContentText("Notification Text1")
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());


}


public void generateNotification2(Context context) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager2 = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent repeating_intent2 = new Intent(context, BuddhaNow.class);
    // replace the old activity if there is a case that it is already opened
    repeating_intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 101, repeating_intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder2 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent2)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())

            .setContentTitle("Notification Title2")
            .setContentText("Notification Text2")
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    notificationManager2.notify(101, builder2.build());


}

public void generateNotification3(Context context) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager3 = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent repeating_intent3 = new Intent(context, BuddhaNow.class);
    // replace the old activity if there is a case that it is already opened
    repeating_intent3.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 102, repeating_intent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder3 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent3)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())

            .setContentTitle("Notification Title3")
            .setContentText("Notification Text3")
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    notificationManager3.notify(102, builder3.build());


}

public void generateNotification4(Context context) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager4 = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent repeating_intent4 = new Intent(context, BuddhaNow.class);
    // replace the old activity if there is a case that it is already opened
    repeating_intent4.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent4 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 105, repeating_intent4, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder4 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent4)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())

            .setContentTitle("Notification Title4")
            .setContentText("Notification Text4")
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    notificationManager4.notify(105, builder4.build());


}

}
```

Comment: Because of position 2 & 3 alarm types are RTC. Try to change them to RTC_WAKEUP. the reason is RTC_WAKEUP will wake the device up and deliver the pending intent. On the other hand RTC will deliver the intent only when the device wakes up.

Comment: @VenkateshGoud thanks for replaying I already replaced those with RTC_WAKEUP but still it doesn't work

Comment: Please extends the WakefulBroadcastReceiver instead of BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: @VenkateshGoud I tried this and it still doesn't work. I don't BroadcastReceiver is the problem.  The problem I am having is that one notification waiting for other notification to finish. They should be shown one by one

Comment: can someone  please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [setExact](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) method in order to archive exact time of alarm firing.

But main your problem is that `bundle.getInt("position0")==0` will be always `true` when there is no `position0` in bundle, because of:

> Returns the value associated with the given key, or 0 if no mapping of
>   the desired type exists for the given key.

So, in order to fix that, pass position:

```
intent.putExtra("position", position);
```

and then check it like that inside broadcast receiver:

```
int position = bundle.getInt("position");

switch (position):
    case 0: 
        utils.generateNotification(context);
        break;
    case 1:
        utils.generateNotification1(context);
        break;
    ...
```

Comment: everything works fine after following your guidelines. Now how do I set the alarm so it also notifies even if the device boots or shuts down. As the phone restarts it should be able to keep track of all of the notifications. 
This is what I did in the manifest file
`<receiver android:name="MyReceiver">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
                </action>
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>`

Comment: @timmy24565 please create one more topic for your question. If original question solved by my answer, please mark it as right answer.